# What should we call our chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat

Did you know that we have a [chat room](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/do-trilogy-sites-need-a-third-place/)?  Did you know that we can name it whatever we want?  What name would make sense for the Biblical Hermeneutics [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/biblical-hermeneutics)?

---

Many of the rooms are named after a place where people who are the audience of the site might get a bite to eat or just hang out:

**Christianity:** [The Upper Room](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1099/914)

**Meta.StackExchange:** Tavern on the Meta

**Philosophy:** Philosophy Café

**SciFi:** Mos Eisley

But there's no reason we couldn't go with something else:

**Chemistry:** The Periodic Table

**SuperUser:** Root Access

**Cooking:** The Frying Pan

**DBA:** The Heap

**Linguistics:** lɪŋˈgwɪstɪks

But we should pick something that reflects our community even if it doesn't communicate much to outsiders:

**Mi Yodeya:** [V'dibarta Bam](http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/vedibarta-bam/)

---

Since discussion has died down on this, I've accepted the top-voted answer (which I also happen to like) and unless there are objections, I'll change the chat room name soon.  If a better name comes along, we can change it again.  (But I expect we'll be happy in the Library for a very long time.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The Library

Pros:

- Vaguely academic sounding
- Not religious (I think this is a 'Pro' because this is an academic site, not primarily a religious one, and not because I think 'religious' is a bad thing)

Cons:

- You aren't supposed to talk in a library (but online chat is more like passing notes so maybe it's ok) :-)

Comment: I just realized: we ♦ moderators are like librarians!

Comment: I talked a lot at my library at school... oops!

Comment: The con [turns out to be a major one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8843178#8843178). I actually think it's a fine name, but the irony is notable esp. considering how verbose our folks can be.

Answer (score 4):

### [Qumran](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qumran)

Pros:

- We are a community dedicated to the preservation of knowledge about ancient texts.
- The Dead Sea Scrolls found there were, perhaps, the most important Biblical discoveries ever made.
- It's a little bit of an inside joke to make people think.
- I like `Q`.

Cons:

- I'm not sure we want to be associated with an [expired religious sect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qumran#Qumran-Essene_hypothesis).

Comment: And just what prompted Qum to get moving inthe first place, hmmm?

Comment: I like it, though I believe it's a bit too localized for the whole site.

Answer (score 3):

### [The Scriptorium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptorium)

Pros:

- Focused on the texts, their transmission, and meaning
- Academic and bookish
- Feeling of antiquity

Cons:

- Religious connotation
- Place for work, not for relaxing and, well, chatting

Answer (score 2):

## The Wilderness

Pros:

- It was a place where people received food and drink from heaven
- It represents a place of testing, just as ideas are tested in the chat room
- It's where people can go to grumble :)

Cons:

- Generally it's a pretty negative place to be, which is maybe not the impression we want to give

Answer (score 2):

### The Hermeneutical Circle

Pros:

- Is a primary focus of this SE.
- Not testamentally, or even textually attached. It could be applied to the classics as well.
- "Circle" can be understood as an area of influence and interaction

Cons:

- Apparently, there is debate as to the semantics of the [word "circle" as a learning device.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeneutic_circle#Critique)

Answer (score 2):

### The Drashing Place

Pros:

- It means a place to sit and talk Torah- drash being what midrash comes from.

Cons:

- Few will get the reference.

Answer (score -1):

## Jacob's Well

Pros:

- It's a place where people gather to talk and drink
- The food there is not real food, but a conversation

Cons:

- It's only referenced in the NT

Comment: Abraham's Well? Abraham's Tent?  Moses' Tent?  Do any of these work to cover all traditions?